# How to write a short grammatically correct query that generates an error when run?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to write a query which:

- as short as possible
- grammatically correct to MySQL server
- makes server returning an error when executed

My current solution is:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (i INT);
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES (2);
SELECT 1 FROM FOO WHERE 1 = (SELECT i FROM FOO);
```

However I don't like it - it is too long.

Comment: What's wrong with `select * from nonexisting_table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some short queries that are all "correct" but will fail

```
SELECT *

SELECT 1e333

SELECT i FROM(SELECT 1i,1i)
```

The verbose versions are

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL

SELECT 1e333 FROM DUAL

SELECT i FROM (SELECT 1 as i, 1 as i FROM DUAL)
```

They fail for different reasons:

1) DUAL does not have any columns.

2) 1e333 does not fit into a float.

3) The inner query returns a table with two identical named columns. Thus specifying this column name is not admissible for the outer query.

Comment: `select *` is not a grammatically correct SQL statement, as you asked initially.

Comment: Then he should use SELECT 1e333

Comment: I executed select * and mysql did not complain of any 'syntax error', so i presumed it is grammatically correct?

Comment: ok you're right, [grammar doesn't require FROM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

Answer (score 2):

```sql
CREATE TABLE FOO (i INT);
CREATE TABLE FOO (i INT);
```

It will not accept to create the table because it already exists after the first statement.

Comment: Hmm, what about DROP TABLE DUAL ? Or DROP TABLE " "  ? Even shorter: DROP VIEW " ";

Comment: yeah, the thing is it should fail all the times. `DROP TABLE DUAL` might not fail if `DUAL` exists. `DROP TABLE " "` I don't know if it's authorized / undefined behavior? But yes, it might be a good solution.

Comment: This is defined behaviour. However 99.9%of the time there will exist no view named " ". Otherwise try DROP VIEW " "; DROP VIEW " ";