# How to write a grammartically correct MySQL expression that generates a runtime error?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is related to:
[How to write a short grammatically correct query that generates an error when run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963184/how-to-write-a-short-grammatically-correct-query-that-generates-an-error-when-ru)

But instead of a whole query, is there a simple grammatically correct *expression* to generate a runtime error when evaluated?

Something like:

```
SELECT IF(1=1, 1, <runtime_error_expression>); // successfully run
SELECT IF(1=2, 1, <runtime_error_expression>); // runtime error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT IF(1=1, 1, 9223372036854775807 + 1); 
SELECT IF(1=2, 1, 9223372036854775807 + 1);
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT IF(1=1, 1, 9223372036854775807 + 1); 
+-------------------------------------+
| IF(1=1, 1, 9223372036854775807 + 1) |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                   1 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF(1=2, 1, 9223372036854775807 + 1); 
ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT value is out of range in '(9223372036854775807 + 1)'
```

---

If use it a lot then you may consider to create a function that generates an error

```
CREATE FUNCTION GEN_ERROR() RETURNS INT
RETURN (SELECT a FROM non_table);
```

If using MySql 5.5 and up you can wrap [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) in your function instead

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION GEN_ERROR() RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000';
  RETURN 1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then use it

```
SELECT IF(1=1, 1, GEN_ERROR()); 
SELECT IF(1=2, 1, GEN_ERROR());
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT IF(1=1, 1, GEN_ERROR()); 
+-------------------------+
| IF(1=1, 1, GEN_ERROR()) |
+-------------------------+
|                       1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF(1=2, 1, GEN_ERROR());
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.non_table' doesn't exist
```

Comment: this is brilliant `SELECT IF(1=2, 1, 9223372036854775807 + 1); `

Answer (score 0):

You could use a procedure and [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) statement that raises an error (MySQL 5.5). For example -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1()
BEGIN

  IF @var = 1 THEN
    SELECT * FROM DUAL;
  ELSE
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02001'; -- Error
  END IF;

END
```